# Package for inline editing in another major mode

Tags: major-mode

I work a lot with Typescript files for Angular 2. The whole HTML structure is packaged in a quote. I would like to select that quote, and edit it in another mode (HTML/Web mode), then save it back to the buffer with the Typescript mode.

I knew there is another package for that, but I cannot find it back. Even not on emacs.zeef.com and Google.

Does anyone recognize which package I mean?

Comment: You might want to look into [polymode](https://github.com/vspinu/polymode).

Comment: You can also try mmm-mode.

Comment: Also have a look at indirect buffers in the emacs manual.

Comment: I've used [nXhtml](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs?action=browse;oldid=NxhtmlMode;id=nXhtml) for such editing.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [edit-indirect](https://github.com/Fanael/edit-indirect):

> Edit regions in separate buffers, like `org-edit-src-code' but for arbitrary
>    regions.